# Are there coventions on reporting weighted sample sizes?

Tags: sample-size, weighted-mean, survey-weights, social-science, sample-weighting

Suppose I analyze survey data and calculate weighted means. Should I report the sample size if it differs from the unweighted sample size, as would be the case with non-normalized weights? It seems pointless to me because these are artifical numbers, not real observations. But I was unable to find any reporting conventions.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you will report weighted averages or proportions. Usually weights are based on a reference population,eg, the United States or New York City. This basis for weights should be reported. Usually, the total sample size should be reported. Subsample sizes, eg, women over 65, are not usually informative and would overload your tables.

You might want to only report statistics if the underlying number of respondents meets a reasonable minumum, eg 40 respondents.